# Match Filter with specific Method through NameBinding on RESTeasy

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to specify a pre-matching filter that is only associated to some of my API calls, by following what the [RESTeasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1316) suggests. Here is what my code looks like:

Name binding:

```
@NameBinding
public @interface ValidateFoo {}
```

Resource:

```
@Path("/foo/bar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FooBar {
    @GET
    @ValidateFoo
    public Object doStuff() {
        //do stuff
    }

    @POST
    public Object doAnotherStuff() {
        //do another stuff
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
@ValidateFoo
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class FooValidation implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
        //validate stuff
    }
}
```

Problem is: the FooValidation filter runs before *every* method call (e.g.: before GETs and POSTs to /foo/bar), not only the ones annotated with `@ValidateFoo` (seems a bug to me). If I remove the `@Provider` annotation from the filter, it won't run before any call (as expected).

I am seeing this behavior consistently, either using WebLogic or Tomcat. My dependency management is done through Maven, and the RESTeasy version is 3.0-beta-3.

Anyone experiencing/experienced the same behavior? I have seen another user with a similar problem on [JBoss forums](https://community.jboss.org/message/777014), with no luck so far.

UPDATE:
Still experiencing the same issue with RESTeasy 3.0.1-Final.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar problem. For me the solution was to add following annotation configuration (to @ValidateFoo):

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but even after the change, the filter still ends up being called before every single call to my app, not only the ones annotated with @ValidateFoo.

Comment: Ok, now we were able to make it work. It looks like RESTeasy did not like the `@PreMatching` annotation. By following your suggestion and removing the `@PreMatching` annotation, everything worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: It kind of makes sense, because `@PreMatching` means before mapping the request to RESTEasy resource, so at that point RESTEasy doesn't know if there is any namebinding.

Comment: "Any `@NameBinding` named binding annotations will be ignored on
a component annotated with the `@PreMatching` annotation." -- javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching

Comment: just as an emphasis. Retention's default is CLASS and not runtime. thus you need it.